# I'm confused on how i'd go about overloading the + operator on a stack using a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack

First of all, i know how to do this using a linked list in general, which i will paste below:

```
    List operator+(const List& l) const
    {
        // copy the first list
        List t = *this;
        Node *n = l.head;

        // iterate through the second list and copy each element to the new list
        while (n != NULL && !t.IsFull())
        {
            t.InsertAfter(n->data);
            n = n->link;
        }

        return t;
    }
```

Now in my Stack i have something that looks like this:

```
Stack operator+(const Stack& s) const
    {
        // copy the first list
        Stack t = *this;
        Node *n = s.top;

        // iterate through the second list and copy each element to the new list
        while (n != NULL && !t.IsFull())
        {
            t.Push(n->data);
            n = n->link;
        }

        return t;
    }
```

My question i guess would be, would this be the right way of going about it? And i'd like to apologize in advance if the Title of this question isn't very clear, i had trouble even figuring out how to word it.

Edit:

I came out with a loop looking like this in reference to Caleb's answer:

```
        Stack t = *this;
        Stack u = *this;
        Node *n = s.top;
while (n != NULL && !t.IsFull())
        {
            t.Push(n->data);
            u.Push(n->data);
            n = n->link;
        }

        return t;
    }
```

Comment: What order do you expect to see for the added items? Should they appear in the back? In the front? In what order should they appear?

Comment: Well i believe since it's a stack the elements would appear from the "bottom" or back and then build up? Sorry if that's not anymore clear

Comment: If you edit your question with an example of stack A, stack B, and (stack A + stack B), that should bring a lot more clarity to the question.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I'm sorry i'm a little confused by that, the first portion of code is just a linked list and the second part of the code is a linked list using a Stack, i only have one stack, if i'm understanding you correctly lol.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable implementation to me.

Comment: Actually question is not clear. Can you please Edit Your question? and  please Do add your actual Problem statement It will help us to get some Idea..

Comment: I mean something like this: `Stack A = {1,2,3}`, `Stack B = {6, 7, 8}`. Adding them should produce `Stack C = {???}` (fill in the question marks to show what should happen).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> would this be the right way of going about it?

You're pushing items from the top of `s` onto `t`, and that means that the items from `s` will appear on `t`, but in reverse order compared to what they were on `s`. If that's what you want, your implementation is fine, but it's hard to think of a situation where that behavior would be useful or expected. Pushing from the bottom of `s` to the top would fix the problem, but that's not an option if you have to stick strictly to stack operations. Another option that uses only stack operations is to first reverse `s` by pushing them one at a time onto an intermediate stack, and then reverse again by pushing onto `t`.

Comment: i edited the loop in the function to see if it would fit this.