# My 3rd stack is printing out in reverse order from my 1st and 2nd stack

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack

Below i will show the output of my program when ran:
[image]

Now i will show the expected out put:

[image]

I will show the function that my professor's code is implementing, or rather the "Copy constructor" or overload function that i made below:

```
void operator=(const Stack& s)
    {
        if (s.top == NULL){
            num_items = 0;
            top = NULL;}
        else
        {
            top = new Node;
            top->data = s.top->data;
            Node* newP = top;
                num_items = 1;
                for(Node* curr = s.top->link; curr != NULL; curr = curr->link)

                {
                    if(num_items != MAX_SIZE)
                    {
                    newP->link = new Node;
                    newP = newP->link;
                    newP->data = curr->data;
                    ++num_items;
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

Lastly i will show the code that is using this function, my instructor's code:

```
    Stack<int> s3;
s3 = s3 + s2;
cout << "*declare s3 as a copy of s2 (stack s3 = s2)\ns3=" << s3 << endl; // copy constructor (=)
cout << "s3.Size()=" << s3.Size() << endl;
cout << "s3.IsEmpty()=" << ((s3.IsEmpty()) ? "T" : "F") << endl;
cout << "s3.IsFull()=" << ((s3.IsFull()) ? "T" : "F") << endl;
cout << "s3.Peek()=" << s3.Peek() << endl;
cout << endl;
```

I've tried various things like making a bot pointer to try and pin point where the bottom of the stack is to then print it out like that, but it didn't seem to work or i wrote it incorrectly.

On request this is the operator+ code:

```
    Stack operator+(const Stack& s) const
    {
        // copy the first list
        Stack t = *this;
        Stack u = *this;
        Node *n = s.top;

        // iterate through the second list and copy each element to the new list
        while (n != NULL && !t.IsFull())
        {
            t.Push(n->data);
            u.Push(n->data);
            n = n->link;
        }

        return u;
    }
```

Comment: `s3` is supposed to be a copy of `s2`? Then why are you doing `s3 = s3 + s2`?

Comment: @remyabel My instructor wrote the main function of this so i'm honestly not sure , i'm not allowed to change anything in his code though

Comment: In that case, show the `operator+`.

Comment: @remyabel i have edited it to show that function

Comment: @remyabel http://ideone.com/o3n1fG <----, that is a pasting of both classes along with every output further down below it, i'm sorry i'm having trouble understanding what you mean by class default.

Comment: No I deleted my comment because I realized that I made the mistake of initializing it on the same line.

Comment: @remyabel i thought maybe, i can't raelly recall what i did on the `operator+` function but i think i may be trying to already reverse it back to normal,but when i tried removing `Stack u = *this` along with the pushing and returning t instead it still gave me the same output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, it seems you didn't follow [Caleb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21718597/1508519)'s advice properly:

> You're pushing items from the top of `s` onto `t`, and that means that the
>   items from `s` will appear on `t`, but in reverse order compared to what
>   they were on `s`. [...] Another option that uses only stack operations
>   is to first reverse `s` by pushing them one at a time onto an
>   intermediate stack, and then reverse again by pushing onto `t`.

`t` would be your intermediate stack, and `u` would contain the items in the correct order. Change your code to the following:

```
// Populate the intermediate stack
while (n != NULL && !t.IsFull())
{
  t.Push(n->data);
  n = n->link;
}

// Begin popping the intermediate stack
// into the resulting stack
n = t.top;
while (n != NULL && !t.IsEmpty())
{
  u.Push(n->data);
  t.Pop();
  n = t.top;
}
```

Also, in order to fix the incorrect size, please use the code from one of your other questions. Replacing your current `operator=` code with the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21749406/1508519) fixes the issue:

```
Stack& operator=( const Stack& rhs ){
  // call this->clear() to avoid memory leak
  if( rhs.top == NULL ){ top = NULL; return *this; }
  Node** store = &top;
  for( Node* curr = rhs.top; curr != NULL; curr = curr->link ){
    Node* newNode = new Node;
    num_items++;
    newNode->data = curr->data;
    *store = newNode;
    store = &newNode->link;
  }
  return *this;
}
```

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/374af662dd2d550f)

Output:

```
*declare s3 as a copy of s2 (stack s3 = s2)
s3=81 64 49 36 25 16 9 4 1 0 
s3.Size()=10
s3.IsEmpty()=F
s3.IsFull()=F
s3.Peek()=81
```

Comment: Wow..thank you so much, i misinterpreted what he said and thought my function was reversing it the right way.

Comment: @Breon No problem, I appreciate you posting the full code sample, but some parts of your code are still incorrect. I would suggest going back through your other questions and reviewing the answers in more detail as you can see that I used two of them to solve the problem.

Comment: yes i just noticed, i still have some errors and a stack printing out where they shouldn't be, thank you again.